# Storing and retrieving a static IP address in a non-standard location in Debian

Tags: linux, networking, debian, static-ip

I need to store my static IP address in a non-standard location; say an EEPROM. This can be retrieved  using a shell command.

Is it possible to configure `/etc/network/interfaces` file in such a way that this shell command is run every-time the network is started/restarted and the IP configuration is read from the non-standard location and used to configure the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution exists, but it is just a variation of what has been suggested already by **strangeman**. [This Debian Wiki link](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Bringing_up_an_interface_without_an_IP_address) shows how to bring up an interface without an IP address, a procedure which is used, for instance, every time a `bridge` is needed with the underlying `eth0` interface having no IP address whatsoever.

In the file `/etc/network/interfaces` add the following lines:

```
    iface eth0 inet manual
      pre-up ip link set $IFACE up
      post-up /path/to/script/which_changes_your_ip.sh
      post-down ip link set $IFACE down
      post-down ip addr flush dev $IFACE
```

In fact, the manual (`man interfaces`) states:

> **The manual Method**
>
> This  method  may be used to define interfaces for which no configuration is done by default. Such interfaces can
>          be configured manually by means of up and down commands or /etc/network/if-*.d scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use post-up command. https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Bringing_up_an_interface_without_an_IP_address

```
iface eth0 inet static
        address some_address
        netmask 255.255.192.0
        gateway some_gateway
        post-up /path/to/script/which_changes_your_ip.sh
```

Comment: So use a dummy address for  "some_address" and do the actual network configuration using "ifconfig" in the  post-up script?

Comment: Yes, why not? :)

Comment: Seems like a hack. Let me see if there is a better solution.